# How to describe this structure in spoken words?

Tags: probability, notation, terminology, binomial-coefficients

$$\large f(0) = P(X = 0) = \frac{\binom{3}{0}\binom{17}{2}}{\binom{20}{2}} = \frac{68}{95},$$

I'm working on annotating math (probability and statistics) for the visually impaired that is to be read aloud by a screen reader and don't know what to put for this structure.

As of now, I've just got something like, "$f$ of zero equals", then I am not sure how to phrase $P(X=0)$ (is it the probability where $X = 0? $), and then really have no idea about those structures in parentheses in the quotient portion.

Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If this is at a beginning level:

> $f$ of zero equals the probability that $X$ equals $0$; this is a fraction whose numerator is $3$ choose $0$ times $17$ choose $2$, and whose denominator is $20$ choose $2$. This evaluates to the fraction $68$ over $95$.

If the students are a bit more advanced, you can compress it a bit:

> $f$ of zero equals the probability that $X$ equals $0$, which is $3$ choose $0$ times $17$ choose $2$ all over $20$ choose $2$, which simplifies to $68$ over $95$.

Comment: Thank you. I may have quite a few of these as I go. Is there a best place/way to ask this without becoming obtrusive? I'd Google it if I knew how but I'm not sure it's possible (even reverse image searching seems far fetched).

Comment: +1 I would explicitly use "the number of ways to choose..." or combinations for more clarity. Ex: the number of ways to choose $2$ items form $17$ items, or the number of combinations to choose $2$ out of $17$.

Comment: @Chelonian: I don’t know of any better place to ask. Perhaps by choosing judiciously you can get enough ideas from a limited number of questions to let you come up with reasonable verbalizations for the rest.

Comment: @msm: I’d do that only for the most inexperienced of students: there’s a point at which expanded verbiage becomes more confusing than helpful. Moreover, you want them to get used to the *n choose k* verbal construction as soon as possible.

Comment: Is there a downside to using "over" instead of "all over" for the division? I always thought of "all over" as a way to distinguish $(a+b)/c$ from $a+(b/c)$, or $(ab)/c$ from $a(b/c)$. Since the latter two expressions are equivalent, I'd never have thought to use "all over" to distinguish them.

Comment: @Vectornaut: I don’t have strong feelings either way; I simply chose the verbalization that reflects the written form. I think this slightly preferable, since the written form in turn accurately reflects the essential idea of dividing the number of (equally likely) successful outcomes by the number of possible outcomes.

Comment: Ah! Reflecting the written form does sound like a good idea.

Answer (score 6):

There are so many different ways that you can do this. Fractions can be read as "[something] divided by [something else]", "numerator: [something] denominator: [something else]" or variations thereupon. Each version has its benefits, so I recommend experimenting with it. As for parenthesis, reading them out loud is not always necessary. In your example, you can get away with not reading them. Nonetheless, I think pauses after each function is helpful to the listener. Here is my recommendation:

> "$f$ of $0$ [pause] equals the probability that $X$ equals $0$ [pause] equals $3$ chose $0$ [pause] times $17$ chose $2$ [pause] divided by $20$ chose $2$ [pause] equals $68$ $95^{\text{ths}}$"

Answer (score 3):

I would read it as the probability that X equals zero, then three choose zero times seventeen choose two divided by twenty choose two.

Answer (score 3):

"The probability that $X=0$ is equal to $3$ choose $0$ times $17$ choose $2$ in the numerator devided by $20$ choose $2$ in the denominator, which is equal to $68$ over $95$".

Answer (score 3):

I feel that reading it like: $f (0)$ equals the probability of $X=0$ given by $3$ choose $2$ times $17$ choose $2$ divided by $20$ choose $2$ which equals $68$ over $95$. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'd adjust the last word "by".  At least to my ear, the word "by" doesn't connote division: it could just as well refer to some form of multiplication or concatenation (e.g. "2 by 3 matrix").

Comment: @ErickWong: I believe it's common in some parts of the world like India to hear "m by n" instead of "m over n", but I'm not sure why. I think it's an error due to translation.

Comment: Rohan, I also suggest you edit your answer. Note that "by" is used in phrases like "m by n grid" or "one by one". In the phrase "m divided by n" the prepositional phrase "by n" specifies how m is divided, and the verb "divided" cannot be omitted.